# Problem with textured panel lines and aliasing

Tags: antialiasing

I have a problem with aliasing and jagged lines.  Using B2.91 on Mac.

I've created a mesh of an aircraft wing and I want to use an image texture created on PS to create fine panel lines. My thought was the fine lines can be applied as both a color and also a bump map to give the appearance of real panel seams on the aircraft.

I created a 4k x 4k image .png file using PS. I UV-unwrapped the wing and applied the texture.  Panel lines that are curved or are not horizontal/vertical come out aliased.  They sort of look OK at a distance but close up it's poor. The picture below shows the problem.

Looking for any suggestion to reduce this aliasing or alternate method to create panel lines on a smooth mesh. (i have tried many tuts but many fail on these gently curved surfaces).  Shall I go beyond 4Kx4K? is this something to fix in PS first?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Matt

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Yes, using a higher res image is the way to go. Since the line is very thin, even in 4K it's only described by a few pixels. Bump mapping especially gives bad artifacts for low res textures.

Comment: Please show a close-up of the problematic area on your texture. If it's pixelated, then there's your problem. Bump mapping isn't always the greatest way to go, try using a normal map converter (many free tools available), instead of the cycles built-in bump node.

Comment: thank you for comments.  There is a close up shown - see the bottom part of the posted image - that intersection of two lines.  It's pixelated.  I will look into normal map converter and also higher res texture (but i'm at 4K x 4K already)

Comment: ah you mean just the texture - yes it's pixelated (when i view the texture and zoom an equivalent amount).  I see your point - i'd need to fix it on PS or use higher res.  Will look into the other ways too.